# Variable Text Size for Illustrator Variables

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Using Adobe Illustrator, I have imported a list of data from a CSV file into illustrator variables.

I'm wondering if I can have different font sizes for each record. Some records are longer than others and don't exactly fit into the design. I would have to optimize each record individually.

Comment: I think it would be very bad for the readability of your table if every line has a diffrent font size

Answer (score 1):

You have some options for manipulating your text after the data is populated. Realistically, most such changes are accomplished by using a custom script. For example, a script can detect overset text and size down the font accordingly. What you can do is find an existing script (may be hard) or ask a scripter from Adobe forums or elance to make you one that just reduces font. Then, place that script into your Illustrator/...Presets/.....Scripts/ folder so that it shows up in the File > Scripts menu. Then, this script can be inserted into your action (Insert Menu Item) which batch-processes the datasets. This will run the script on each of your document right after the dataset is populated. This is admittedly a very brief explanation.

Comment: Let me add an article that explains this a little further:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/adobe-illustrator-variable-data-dealing-overset-text-vasily-hall?trk=prof-post

Comment: Another article which uses an "Actions-only" approach which is not advised, but is nevertheless a valid workaround for those situations where it may be deemed appropriate: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/illustrator-variable-data-exploratory-techniques-using-vasily-hall